# Why do I seem to need both a promise and a callback to expose JSON data to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, callback, promise

As I understand it to expose fetched JSON data to a global variable I need to use either a promise or a callback function. My code is working but it's using both...

I'm creating a promise using jQuery's `.done`, I would like to instantiate my `nowNext()` function within `.done`. Shouldn't code within `.done` only be executed once the promise (i.e. the JSON data) is returned ?

If I call `nowNext()` at this point and log my `timeObj` it's an empty object, however if I instantiate `timeCall()` a callback function within `.done` which then instantiates `nowNext()` my `timeObj` gets the JSON data.

```
// define the timeObj globally so the returned JSON can be stored

var timeObj = {};

// function gets JSON feed, argument specifies which object within feed to target

function nowTime(i){

    $.getJSON("feed.json", function(data) {
        console.log('getting JSON...')      
    })

    // a promise only to be executed once data has been fetched
    .done(function(data) { 
        // timeData is whichever JSON object targeted in argument
        timeData = data.programme[i],

        // Start building the timeObj with this data
        timeObj = {
            title:        timeData.title,
            startTime:    timeData.start
        }

        // timeCall instantiates the nowNext function only  
        // once the timeObj has all it's key/values defined
        // directly calling nowNext at this point logs timeObj as an empty object...
        timeCall();
    })

    .fail(function() {
      console.log( "error" );
    })
};

// instantiate nowTime to fetch data of current/now programme 
$(function(){ 
    nowTime(0) 
})

// callback so that when nowNext is instantiated
// nowTime has already fetched timeObj data
function timeCall(){
    nowNext();
}

function nowNext() {
    console.log(timeObj)
}
```

A sample of the JSON data being fetched:

```
//////// feed.json ////////

{
   "programme" : [
      {
         "title" : "Rick & Morty",
         "startTime" : "19:00",
      },
      {
         "title" : "News",
         "startTime" : "19:30",
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your code looks fine to me. The function you pass to `.done()` is called when the Promise is resolved, and that happens when the `getJSON()` response is received. In that callback, you invoke (indirectly) `nowNext()`, so the global variable will have been initialized. What exactly is not clear about it?

Comment: this is probably because of the async delayed evaluation of objects logged to the console

Comment: How many functions you use is up to you. You can put the `console.log(timeObj)` call directly inside `timeCall` or even inside `done`. It won't make a difference.

Comment: @Pointy why can't I call `nowNext()` directly within `.done`?

Comment: @AlanSutherland there's absolutely no reason why you can't - be aware that `console.log` does odd things on occasion

Comment: Don't blindly trust the console. Use a debugger to step through your code or  log a serialized version of the data. However, the best solution would be to pass the data **to** the function. Mixing async operations and global state is ... messy.

Comment: Make sure you aren't shadowing global `timeObj` inside `nowTime` or the then handler. That'd be the only way `timeObj` of `nowNext` be different.

Comment: the console is only an example, the actual function is using it to update the title/time of progs but without the callback function it returns undefined on both

Comment: @FelixKling is there a better way to pass data to the function?

Comment: Pass the value is an argument: `nowNext(data.programme[i])` with `function nowNext(data) { console.log(data) }`.

Comment: ah right, nice :) thanks

Comment: better yet, have `.done()` do `return timeObj` and then do `.then(nowNext)` in the Promise chain at which point the object is passed automatically

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak I'll try that out too

Comment: @AlanSutherland see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid global variables.  When you start making asynchronous calls you need to ensure that all following code happens via the callbacks / Promise chains, with the variables passed around as parameters if possible.

My preferred solution for this would be:

```
function nowTime(i){   
    return $.getJSON("feed.json", function(data) {  // NB: return
        console.log('getting JSON...')      
    }).then(function(data) { 
        // timeData is whichever JSON object targeted in argument
        timeData = data.programme[i],

        // Start building a timeObj with this data
        return {
            title:        timeData.title,
            startTime:    timeData.start
        }
    });
};

function nowNext(timeObj) {
    ...
}

$(function(){ 
    nowTime(0).then(nowNext).fail(...); 
});
```

By having the `.done` callback actually return the subset of data that you require (albeit still encapsulated within a Promise) and then invoking `nowNext` via `.then`, you ensure that the data is automatically passed down the promise chain.

Notice also that error handling is also done via the Promise chain - if the `nowTime` function returns a rejected promise (or throws an exception) the following `.then` call is automatically skipped and the code will fall through to the `.fail` handler.